# how to convert base 64 string to html UTF8 format?

Tags: java

I am getting HTML data in buffer which is encoded. How to decode them so that I will get it in proper HTML format.

[image: attached image contains the encrypted HTML data]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking at the moment. That data isn't base64, which in turn isn't an encryption scheme. If this content is actually encrypted, you'll need to know the encryption scheme and a key to decrypt it. Could you give more context for how you're fetching this data, and any other headers? (It may just be compressed rather than encrypted.)

Comment: Decode the Base64 text to a String and then encode it as UTF-8.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting this data from Buffer. In the provided image you can see its content type is text/html; UTF-8. Further WebClient, vert.x  is used in this code.

Comment: Well that's clearly *not* UTF-8 text, nor base64. I very much suspect that there are other headers we can't see, such as a Content-Encoding. I have no idea what your last comment means, I'm afraid. Please edit your question to provide a *lot* more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet do you know how to bind this data coming from buffer using webClient api?

Comment: Again, we need more information. It would be *really* helpful if you'd provide a [mcve]. At the moment, I'd be trying to guess what your code is doing, and that's not good for either of us.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code to decode

```
Base64.decodeBase64(string);
```

Comment: Base64 is ASCII text - this isn't.